# Type error on a function that return a object based on a api get

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, hook

So basically I want to create a function that does a GET method in my API using an id received as params. As I'm coding a hook, I'm trying to export this function as well.
But, I'm suffering from this error:
[image: Error that appears]

Code:

```
import { api } from '../services/api';

interface Transaction{
  _id: string,
  name: string,
  amount: number,
  type: 'deposit' | 'withdraw'
  createdAt: string,
}


interface TransactionContextData{
  transactions: Transaction[]
  getTransactionById: (transactionId: String) => Promise<Transaction>
}

const TransactionsContext = createContext<TransactionContextData>({} as TransactionContextData)

export function TransactionsProvider({children}:TransactionsProviderProps){
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState<Transaction[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    getTransactions()
  }, []);


  async function getTransactionById(transactionId: String){
    api.get(`transactions/${transactionId}`)
    .then((reponse) => {return reponse.data});
  }


  return (
    <TransactionsContext.Provider value={{ transactions, createTransaction, deleteTransaction, updateTransaction, getTransactions, getTransactionById}}>
      {children}
    </TransactionsContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useTransactions(){
  const context = useContext(TransactionsContext)

  return context
}
```

Comment: MIght need a `return` on `api.get`?

Comment: Shesh. It was that!

Answer (score 1):

It just needs a return right before the api.get